# DISCONNECTED - during karma unit test execution after ~2000 using gulp, can anyone know to resolve this issue?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularjs-1.6, gulp-karma

> Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 2009 of 2294 (45 FAILED) DISCONNECTED (7 mins 21.244 secs / 6 mins 16.904 secs)

Karma version: 0.13.22

gulp --version:-

[12:18:06] CLI version 3.9.1

[12:18:06] Local version 3.9.1

Comment: what command are you using? Have you tried with `watch` with `gulp`.

Comment: i am trying with "gulp test"

Comment: I am not sure, how you configure your `gulpfile.js`. but something like you can try. I am not clear here. 
`gulp.task('test', done => {
  config.karma.singleRun = true;
  karmaServer(config.karma, done);
});`

  For  watching:  
`gulp.task('test.watch', done => {
  karmaServer(config.karma, done);
});`

Comment: i am also using the same configuration which you provided on above comment.but it is not working when i running with watch